# PL SQL My query says Compiled Successfully, but cannot find the result

Tags: oracle, plsql

My query says Compiled Successfully, but cannot find the result. Can anyone advise?  New to PLSQL. Thanks

Comment: Compilation just means your program is in an executable state. That is your CREATE PROCEDURE statement has no compilation errros. It does not mean the procedure has  actually executed. For that to happen you need to run it. If you want more help than that please post your code and we can show you how to run it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understood the problem.

You didn't specify what you exactly did (what kind of a PL/SQL code is it?), but - it could be a stored procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test as
  2  begin
  3    dbms_output.put_line('Hello');
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.
```

or perhaps an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('Hello');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Both of these are supposed to display the "Hello" message. Obviously, neither of them did. I don't know what your PL/SQL code does, but - if it also displays *something*, enable the output. In SQL*Plus, SQL Developer and some other tools that support it, you'd run

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
```

If it is a stored procedure you created, you have to *execute* it to see the result:

```
SQL> exec p_test
Hello                                     --> "Hello" is here!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Or, if it is an anonymous PL/SQL block, you don't have to do anything special:

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('Hello');
  3  end;
  4  /
Hello                                     --> "Hello" is here!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

See if this helps. If not, explain the problem a little bit better and we'll try to assist.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to create a function/procedure/package although you haven't shown us your code.

Try this:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM all_objects
   WHERE owner = (SELECT user FROM dual) 
     AND object_name = '[Your Object Name]'
    ;
```

It should show you the schema under which your object was created.

Comment: Depending on how you are compiling there are differing methods of getting the actual error messages. If compiling from sqlplus use the command Show Errors. Most other IDEs also have a method to display compile errors but those may be turned off; setting is highly application specific, check your documentation. If nothing else is available then you can use the SQL statement "Select * from user_errors; "